# Rails: Using a form to add records to a model that has a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model-associations

I have access to @result in my view result.html.erb. @result is a Movie object. I'd like to create comments for this @result object through a form. I'm placing the comment box (form) inside result.html.erb.

I'm new to the syntax for forms. I'm also confused about where to direct the form itself to after submitting. Do I need to create a new controller all together for the comments with a create action?

I'm not sure how to create this form so that it is saved to @result.comments.last

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Posted are my models and controller.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mpaa_rating, :poster, :runtime, :synopsis, :title, :year

  has_many :comments

end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :critic, :date, :publication, :text, :url

  belongs_to :movie
end


class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def search
    session[:search] = params[:q].to_s
    redirect_to result_path
  end

  def result
    search_query = search_for_movie(session[:search])
    if !search_query.nil? && Movie.find_by_title(search_query[0].name).nil?
      save_movie(search_query) 
      save_reviews(search_query)
    end
    @result ||= Movie.find_by_title(search_query[0].name)
  end
end
```

result.html.erb

I used to the simple_form gem because I thought it would be better but I think my use case is simple enough to just use a standard rails form helper. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Here's what I wrote so far:

```
<%= simple_form_for @result do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :text %>
  <%= f.input :critic %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I'm receiving the error:

```
undefined method `movie_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001013f4358>:0x00000102d83ad0>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a #create action to the pages controller and placing the form in my view as:

```
        <%= form_for @comment, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_area :text, placeholder: "Compose new review..." %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'critic', "#{current_user.name}"  %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'date', "#{Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}"  %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

In the controller Pages controller

```
  def create
    search_query = search_for_movie(session[:search])
    @movie = Movie.find_by_title(search_query[0].name)
    @comment = @movie.comments.create(text: params[:comment][:text], critic: params[:critic], date: params[:date])
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Review added!"
      redirect_to result_path
    else
      redirect_to result_path
    end
  end
```